# cant render data from database(mongodb, prisma, nextjs13)

Tags: typescript, mongodb, prisma, next.js13

I currently started learning again and wanted to follow a tutorial on how to create my own portfolio. But i thought i can use a database as well as Prisma too in order to improve scalability of my project in the future. So i am trying to implement it by myself however i keep getting an error

**"Property 'projectsData' does not exist on type 'void | { projectsData: { id: string; Description: string; JP_Name: string; Made_using: string[]; Name: string; }[]; }'.ts(2339)" here is my code :**

***page.tsx***

```
export default async function Home() {
  const { projectsData } = await getProjects()

  // const { locales, locale: activeLocale, defaultLocale } = router;
  return (
    <main className="flex flex-col items-center justify-between space-y-5 ">

      {/* <div className="absolute -top-44 -right-52 rounded-full  bg-green-300 opacity-100 dark:bg-pink-500 blur-[20rem] w-[34rem] h-[34rem]"> </div>
      <div className="absolute -top-44 -left-52  rounded-full  bg-purple-300 opacity-100 dark:bg-pink-500 blur-[20rem] w-[34rem] h-[34rem]"> </div> */}


      <Navbar />
      <Intro />
      <ProjectsCards data={projectsData} />
    </main>
```

---

**getProjects() function in "libs/" folder**

```
import prismaClientConnect from './prismaClientConnect'



export async function getProjects() {
    try {
        const projectsData = await prismaClientConnect.projects.findMany()

        return { projectsData }

    } catch (error) {
        return console.log(error)
    } finally {
        return console.log("datafetched")
    }
}
```

**my prisma schema**

```
model Projects {
  id          String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  Description String
  JP_Name     String
  Made_using  String[]
  Name        String
}
```

**prisma prismaClientConnect function**

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

declare global {
  var prisma: PrismaClient | undefined;
}

const prismaClientConnect = new PrismaClient();
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") global.prisma = prismaClientConnect;
export default prismaClientConnect;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is inside `getProjects` function, namely, the fact that  `finally` ***return***s, which overrides the `return`ed value of `try` or `catch`.

To return `projectsData`, remove the `return` from `finally`:

```js
export async function getProjects() {
  try {
    const projectsData = await prismaClientConnect.projects.findMany()

    return { projectsData }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)

    // let's return an empty array on error
    return { projectsData: [] }
  } finally {
    // this no longer overrides the returned values of `try` and `catch`
    console.log('datafetched')
  }
}
```

---

In more detail,

```js
return console.log(anything)
```

will execute the `console.log()` function, printing the value of `anything` in the console, and will return the result of running `console.log`, which is `undefined`.

So `return console.log(anything)` will always return `undefined`, regardless of the value of `anything`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! i rewrote it by the time i saw this answer but i got to learn a lot :)